# Electron Dialog not saving the file

Tags: javascript, dialog, electron

Electron version: **1.3.3**
Operating system: **Ubuntu 14.04**

I want to save a XML object into a .xml file with Electron. I try this:

```
const {dialog} = require("electron").remote; 
dialog.showSaveDialog(myObj)
```

A new windows is opening, I fill the name of the file but nothing has been saving.
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `showSaveDialog()` API does not save the file for you. You must use the returned path and use Node to save your file.

```
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;
const fs = require('fs');

dialog.showSaveDialog({}).then((result) => {
  fs.writeFile(result.filePath, MyFileData, (err) => {
    // file saved or err
  });
}).catch((err) => {
  // err
});
```

Answer (score 10):

it's recommended to use returned path from dialog.showSaveDialog to get `filepath` in new versions of electron: (which is `result.filePath` in the below code)

```
    filename = dialog.showSaveDialog({}
    ).then(result => {
      filename = result.filePath;
      if (filename === undefined) {
        alert('the user clicked the btn but didn\'t created a file');
        return;
      }
      fs.writeFile(filename, content, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          alert('an error ocurred with file creation ' + err.message);
          return
        }
        alert('WE CREATED YOUR FILE SUCCESFULLY');
      })
      alert('we End');
    }).catch(err => {
      alert(err)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I lost one day trying to solve this problem.

Comment: But it doesn't work right if you click cancel btn. You should write if (filename == "") because typeof(filename) is string and filename="" in case of cancel

Comment: Using just `result` for the filename worked for me before, and now it stopped working and I had to use `result.filePath`. Was there an API change?

Comment: @A.Donda before 2May2018 (before v2.0.0) `showSaveDialog` returns a `callback` (not a `Promise` untill 20july2019 (version 6.0.0)) and that callback just has one argument and that was `filePath` but after v2.0.0 it starts to get more options - you can take a look at [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog/history) to see documentations about this classified by versions