# Electron Dialog not saving file

Tags: javascript, dialog, electron

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://codingshiksha.com/electron-drag-and-drop-file-example-with-editing) and it includes a section where a button is pressed. This opens a dialog window to save the contents of a text box as a text file. This is included in the `main.js` file. However when I run it the window opens but when I press save no file gets saved.

```
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain
const fs = require('fs')
const { dialog } = require('electron')

ipcMain.on('clickedbutton', (event, data) => {

    dialog.showSaveDialog({ 
        filters: [{ name: 'text', extensions: ['txt'] }
        ]},function (fileName) {

            if(fileName === undefined) return
            fs.writeFile(fileName, data, function (err) {

            })

     });

})
```

I do not understand how the `fileName` argument is passed to the function. I then tried to separate the dialog window call and the function as suggested [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078170/electron-dialog-saving-file-not-working) but here fileName is an object which does not work.

```
ipcMain.on('clickedbutton',(event,data) => {

    var fileName = dialog.showSaveDialog({});

    fs.writeFile(fileName,data,function(err){});

})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial you linked is outdated. The `dialog` functions changed in Electron 6, changing from a callback-based API (which you have in your code) to a promise-based one.

For Electron >= 6, you want to do the following inside an `async` function. Note that you can replace this function with `dialog.showSaveDialogSync` if you want to run the function synchronously.

```js
  const { filePath, canceled } = await dialog.showSaveDialog({
    defaultPath: "text.txt"
  });

  if (filePath && !canceled) {
    const data = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from('Hello Node.js'));
    fs.writeFile(filePath, data, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('The file has been saved!');
    });
  }
```

Note the option change from `filters` to `defaultPath`, since I'm assuming you want to set a default file name instead of rendering existing files that aren't `text.txt` unselectable by the dialog.

See a [minimal example](https://gist.github.com/erickzhao/8dfbf3b90347c29781bc10f48daf048c) openable in [Electron Fiddle](https://electronjs.org/fiddle). In this example, the dialog opens directly as the browser window open.