# How to save file to local system with specific extension using angular2+electron desktop application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAWbL.png) //my html

```js
save(){
   var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type:            "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
  FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
}
```

```html
 <button mat-stroked-button class="button5 btn-responsive" (click)='save()'>Save</button>
```

This above code only work for web application and not desktop app.

Please help

Comment: use nodejs FS module in the main process and import it to render and write, or send IPC message with blob and handle the write from the backend

Comment: @namila007 I already tried with FS module in angular component.But FS module not supporting to downloading file into local system.

Comment: The above code is work for angular desktop application.The problem is it's not showing save as type .Save as type showing when application run in chrome only.                                            
              https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAWbL.png

Comment: You need to use electron dialogs,

Comment: @namila007 I tried with electron dialog also,But  fs.writeFile()  not working in client side.

Comment: @namila007 how to make fs.writeFile work  in  angular component.

Comment: set `nodeIntegration: true` on your browserWindow and import it on ur angular

Comment: @namila007 so I set nodeIntegration:true in my browserWindow.what thing i need to import in my angular component.

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39090208/6771708